# Perl script to merge lines into a single line between two patterns and print the entire file

Tags: regex, perl

I have a CSV file like below:

File1

```
Module Statements,Module,Collection of primitive building blocks and instances of other modules that comprise a network and or instrument. Two types handoff or internal,A redefinition of a module_def shall overwrite a previously defined module_def having the same module_name within the same nameSpace_name.,6.4.5.a),
Module Statements,,,A module_def shall have at least one port_def unless it is the top module and contains an AccessLink statement,6.4.5.b),
Module Statements,,,"The following objects shall have unique names within a module_def:
port_name
? scanRegister_name
? dataRegister_name
? one_hot_scan_group_name
? scanMux_name
? dataMux_name
? clockMux_name
? one_hot_data_group_name
? logicSignal_name
? alias_name",6.4.5.c),
Module Statements,,,"The following objects shall have unique names within a module_def:
instance_name
? scanInterface_name",6.4.5.d),
Module Statements,,,"An inputPort_name shall be one of the following
scanInPort_name
? shiftEnPort_name
? captureEnPort_name
? updateEnPort_name
? dataInPort_name
? selectPort_name
? resetPort_name
? tmsPort_name
? tckPort_name
? clockPort_name
? trstPort_name
? addressPort_name
? writeEnPort_name
? readEnPort_name
",6.4.5.e),
Module Statements,,,"An outputPort_name shall be one of the following:
? scanOutPort_name
? dataOutPort_name
? toShiftEnPort_name
? toUpdateEnPort_name
? toCaptureEnPort_name
? toSelectPort_name
? toResetPort_name
? toTckPort_name
? toTmsPort_name
? toClockPort_name
? toTrstPort_name
? toIRSelectPort_name",6.4.5.f),
Module Statements,,,Multiple inputPort_name port functions that are of type vector_id may share the same SCALAR_ID as long as the indexes form a contiguous range and every index range is of the same either ascending or descending type.,6.4.5.g),
Module Statements,,,Multiple outputPort_name port functions that are of type vector_id may share the same SCALAR_ID as long as the indexes form a contiguous range and every index range is of the same either ascending or descending type.,6.4.5.h),
```

Output file: Search patterns
Pattern1: Module Statements
Pattern 2: 6.*

This is the desired result - Output file that we require:

Output file
####################################################################

```
Module Statements,Module,Collection of primitive building blocks and instances of other modules that comprise a network and or instrument. Two types handoff or internal,A redefinition of a module_def shall overwrite a previously defined module_def having the same module_name within the same nameSpace_name.,6.4.5.a),
Module Statements,,,A module_def shall have at least one port_def unless it is the top module and contains an AccessLink statement,6.4.5.b),
Module Statements,,,"The following objects shall have unique names within a module_def: port_name ? scanRegister_name ? dataRegister_name ? one_hot_scan_group_name ? scanMux_name ? dataMux_name ? clockMux_name
? one_hot_data_group_name ? logicSignal_name ? alias_name",6.4.5.c),
Module Statements,,,"The following objects shall have unique names within a module_def: instance_name ? scanInterface_name",6.4.5.d),
Module Statements,,,"An inputPort_name shall be one of the following scanInPort_name ? shiftEnPort_name ? captureEnPort_name ? updateEnPort_name
? dataInPort_name ? selectPort_name ? resetPort_name ? tmsPort_name
? tckPort_name ? clockPort_name ? trstPort_name ? addressPort_name
? writeEnPort_name ? readEnPort_name ",6.4.5.e),
Module Statements,,,"An outputPort_name shall be one of the following:
? scanOutPort_name ? dataOutPort_name ? toShiftEnPort_name ?
toUpdateEnPort_name ? toCaptureEnPort_name ? toSelectPort_name
? toResetPort_name ? toTckPort_name ? toTmsPort_name ? toClockPort_name
? toTrstPort_name ? toIRSelectPort_name",6.4.5.f),
Module Statements,,,Multiple inputPort_name port functions that are of type vector_id may share the same SCALAR_ID as long as the indexes form a contiguous range and every index range is of the same either ascending or descending type.,6.4.5.g),
Module Statements,,,Multiple outputPort_name port functions that are of type vector_id may share the same SCALAR_ID as long as the indexes form a contiguous range and every index range is of the same either ascending or descending type.,6.4.5.h),
```

I created the Perl script below, but it's not giving me the result I expected.

Perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use feature 'say';

my @collect;
my $file = $ARGV[0] or die;
open(my $DATA, '<', $file) or die;

while (<$DATA>) {
    chomp;
    # If we're between our markers...
    if (/Module Statements/ .. /6.4*/) {
        # At the start marker, empty the array
        if (/Module Statements/) {
            @collect = ();
        # At the end marker, print the array
        } elsif (/6.4*/) {
            say join ' ', @collect;
        # Otherwise, push the line onto the array
        } else {
            push @collect, $_;
            foreach my $m (@collect) {
                print $m;
            }
        }
    # Otherwise, just print the line
    } else {
        say;
    }
}
```

Thanks and Regards
Kshitij Kulshreshtha

Comment: You have two situations between the before / after csv. At a bare minimum quoted fields are needed for one or both of the field spans lines or the field contains the csv delimiter. These are user selected when fields are constructed. Fixed fields are rare and commonly used in statistics. If the goal is to remove the quotes, the fields must be parsed then remove the line feeds (if desired), then examine the field to see if it contains the current delimiter. If it does you can either change the delimiter to something else or it must be quoted. I have software that does this with a button click.

Comment: The fourth line of your "Output File" (`"? one_hot_data_group_name ?..."`) is peceded by a line terminator. I presume the line terminator should not be there, in which case you should remove it. Same for all other lines that do not begin `"Module Statements,"`. That is, I assume the image of the output file should be as shown in all three answers to date.

Answer (score 1):

Your data are definitively formatted as csv. And because there are no straight forward regex solution to solve it, I recommend you to :

1. Open it as a csv (input.csv) with 6 columns,
2. then remove the feed lines,
3. Write the result into a csv (output.csv)

Here is a code which does it and use this tiny regex `\r?\n` to replace the feed lines in Windows or Unix format :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

# Specify the CSV input file and separator
my $csv_input_file = "input.csv";
my $separator = ",";

# Specify the CSV output file
my $csv_output_file = "output.csv";


# Function to read CSV with 6 columns
sub read_csv {
    my ($file, $separator) = @_;
    my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
        sep_char => $separator,
        binary   => 1,
        eol      => "\n",
        auto_diag => 1,
        strict   => 1,  # Enforce 6 columns per row
    });

    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Could not open '$file': $!";
    my @rows;
    while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
        # Check if the row has exactly 6 columns
        if (@$row != 6) {
            die "Error: Row does not have 6 columns in file '$file': @$row";
        }
        push @rows, $row;
    }
    close $fh or die "Error closing '$file': $!";
    return \@rows;
}


# Function to remove line feeds
sub remove_line_feeds {
    my ($data) = @_;
    for my $row (@$data) {
        for my $field (@$row) {
            $field =~ s/\r?\n/ /g;
        }
    }
}

# Function to write CSV
sub write_csv {
    my ($file, $data, $separator) = @_;
    my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
        sep_char => $separator,
        binary   => 1,
        eol      => "\n",
    });

    open my $fh, '>', $file or die "Could not create '$file': $!";
    foreach my $row (@$data) {
        $csv->print($fh, $row);
    }
    close $fh or die "Error closing '$file': $!";
}

# Read the CSV data
my $csv_data = read_csv($csv_input_file, $separator);

# Remove line feeds from the CSV data
remove_line_feeds($csv_data);

# Write the modified CSV data to the output file
write_csv($csv_output_file, $csv_data, $separator);

print "Modified CSV data saved to '$csv_output_file'.\n";
```

### output.csv:

```
"Module Statements",Module,"Collection of primitive building blocks and instances of other modules that comprise a network and or instrument. Two types handoff or internal","A redefinition of a module_def shall overwrite a previously defined module_def having the same module_name within the same nameSpace_name.",6.4.5.a),
"Module Statements",,,"A module_def shall have at least one port_def unless it is the top module and contains an AccessLink statement",6.4.5.b),
"Module Statements",,,"The following objects shall have unique names within a module_def: port_name ? scanRegister_name ? dataRegister_name ? one_hot_scan_group_name ? scanMux_name ? dataMux_name ? clockMux_name ? one_hot_data_group_name ? logicSignal_name ? alias_name",6.4.5.c),
"Module Statements",,,"The following objects shall have unique names within a module_def: instance_name ? scanInterface_name",6.4.5.d),
"Module Statements",,,"An inputPort_name shall be one of the following scanInPort_name ? shiftEnPort_name ? captureEnPort_name ? updateEnPort_name ? dataInPort_name ? selectPort_name ? resetPort_name ? tmsPort_name ? tckPort_name ? clockPort_name ? trstPort_name ? addressPort_name ? writeEnPort_name ? readEnPort_name ",6.4.5.e),
"Module Statements",,,"An outputPort_name shall be one of the following: ? scanOutPort_name ? dataOutPort_name ? toShiftEnPort_name ? toUpdateEnPort_name ? toCaptureEnPort_name ? toSelectPort_name ? toResetPort_name ? toTckPort_name ? toTmsPort_name ? toClockPort_name ? toTrstPort_name ? toIRSelectPort_name",6.4.5.f),
"Module Statements",,,"Multiple inputPort_name port functions that are of type vector_id may share the same SCALAR_ID as long as the indexes form a contiguous range and every index range is of the same either ascending or descending type.",6.4.5.g),
"Module Statements",,,"Multiple outputPort_name port functions that are of type vector_id may share the same SCALAR_ID as long as the indexes form a contiguous range and every index range is of the same either ascending or descending type.",6.4.5.h),
```

I hope the extra " in the **output.csv** are acceptable for you. As well as the format in only one line.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you wish to remove all line terminators except for those that precede, `"Module Statements,"`. You could do that by replacing matches of the following regular expression with a space.

```
\R(?!Module Statements,)
```

---

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nqt9NJ/1)

As seen at the link, those replacements produce the following string.

```
Module Statements,Module,Collection of primitive building blocks and instances of other modules that comprise a network and or instrument. Two types handoff or internal,A redefinition of a module_def shall overwrite a previously defined module_def having the same module_name within the same nameSpace_name.,6.4.5.a),
Module Statements,,,A module_def shall have at least one port_def unless it is the top module and contains an AccessLink statement,6.4.5.b),
Module Statements,,,"The following objects shall have unique names within a module_def: port_name ? scanRegister_name ? dataRegister_name ? one_hot_scan_group_name ? scanMux_name ? dataMux_name ? clockMux_name ? one_hot_data_group_name ? logicSignal_name ? alias_name",6.4.5.c),
Module Statements,,,"The following objects shall have unique names within a module_def: instance_name ? scanInterface_name",6.4.5.d),
Module Statements,,,"An inputPort_name shall be one of the following scanInPort_name ? shiftEnPort_name ? captureEnPort_name ? updateEnPort_name ? dataInPort_name ? selectPort_name ? resetPort_name ? tmsPort_name ? tckPort_name ? clockPort_name ? trstPort_name ? addressPort_name ? writeEnPort_name ? readEnPort_name ",6.4.5.e),
Module Statements,,,"An outputPort_name shall be one of the following: ? scanOutPort_name ? dataOutPort_name ? toShiftEnPort_name ? toUpdateEnPort_name ? toCaptureEnPort_name ? toSelectPort_name ? toResetPort_name ? toTckPort_name ? toTmsPort_name ? toClockPort_name ? toTrstPort_name ? toIRSelectPort_name",6.4.5.f),
Module Statements,,,Multiple inputPort_name port functions that are of type vector_id may share the same SCALAR_ID as long as the indexes form a contiguous range and every index range is of the same either ascending or descending type.,6.4.5.g),
Module Statements,,,Multiple outputPort_name port functions that are of type vector_id may share the same SCALAR_ID as long as the indexes form a contiguous range and every index range is of the same either ascending or descending type.,6.4.5.h),
```

---

The regular expression reads, "Match a line terminator (`\R`) provided it is not followed by "Module Statements,". `(?!...)` denotes a *negative lookahead*, a condition that must be satisfied but is not part of the match that is returned.

[Here](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/06/the-r-generic-line-ending/) is an explanation of the token `\R` in perl.

---

Each line of the resulting string ends with a comma. If, when writing the string to file (in the normal way) the line-terminating commas denote unwanted empty fields when the file is read as a CSV file, those commas can be stripped by replacing matches of `,(?=\R|\z)` with an empty string (`''`).

`(?=\R|\z)` is a *positive lookahead* that asserts that the match of the comma must be followed by a line terminator or (`|`) the comma is at the end of the string (`\z`).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kAe8xA/1)

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's csv parser is useful here.

Try:

```
ruby -r csv -e 'puts CSV.generate(**{:force_quotes => true}){|csv| 
    CSV.parse($<.read).map{|sa| 
        sa.map{|e| e.nil? ? e : e.gsub(/\R+/,"")}}.each{|row| csv<<row}}' file
```

Prints:

```
"Module Statements","Module","Collection of primitive building blocks and instances of other modules that comprise a network and or instrument. Two types handoff or internal","A redefinition of a module_def shall overwrite a previously defined module_def having the same module_name within the same nameSpace_name.","6.4.5.a)",""
"Module Statements","","","A module_def shall have at least one port_def unless it is the top module and contains an AccessLink statement","6.4.5.b)",""
"Module Statements","","","The following objects shall have unique names within a module_def:port_name? scanRegister_name? dataRegister_name? one_hot_scan_group_name? scanMux_name? dataMux_name? clockMux_name? one_hot_data_group_name? logicSignal_name? alias_name","6.4.5.c)",""
"Module Statements","","","The following objects shall have unique names within a module_def:instance_name? scanInterface_name","6.4.5.d)",""
"Module Statements","","","An inputPort_name shall be one of the followingscanInPort_name? shiftEnPort_name? captureEnPort_name? updateEnPort_name? dataInPort_name? selectPort_name? resetPort_name? tmsPort_name? tckPort_name? clockPort_name? trstPort_name? addressPort_name? writeEnPort_name? readEnPort_name","6.4.5.e)",""
"Module Statements","","","An outputPort_name shall be one of the following:? scanOutPort_name? dataOutPort_name? toShiftEnPort_name? toUpdateEnPort_name? toCaptureEnPort_name? toSelectPort_name? toResetPort_name? toTckPort_name? toTmsPort_name? toClockPort_name? toTrstPort_name? toIRSelectPort_name","6.4.5.f)",""
"Module Statements","","","Multiple inputPort_name port functions that are of type vector_id may share the same SCALAR_ID as long as the indexes form a contiguous range and every index range is of the same either ascending or descending type.","6.4.5.g)",""
"Module Statements","","","Multiple outputPort_name port functions that are of type vector_id may share the same SCALAR_ID as long as the indexes form a contiguous range and every index range is of the same either ascending or descending type.","6.4.5.h)",""
```

If you dont want quotes around each field, change the first line to:

```
puts CSV.generate{|csv| # the rest the same...
```

If you want the `\r\n` replaced by a space (as your example has) then change the `e.gsub(/\R+/,"")` to `e.gsub(/\R+/," ")`

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, if you don't want the space but do want to kill the commas at the ends of lines in the CSV output file (that produce empty fields), you could replace `e.gsub(/\R+/,"")` with `e.gsub(/\R+|,(?=\R+Module Statements,)/,"")`. If you do want the space and want to kill the commas, replace `e.gsub(/\R+/,"")` with `e.gsub(/\R+|,(?=\R+Module Statements,)/) { |s| s == ',' ? '' : ' ' }`.